# Verlet integration with translation and rotation in 2D

Tags: rotational-dynamics, integration

I'm facing with some equations of motion (translation and rotation) in 2D, and I need to integrate them using Verlet approach.

Anyway, I'm stuck with the rotational part. In my framework, bodies lie in the $xy$ plane and they can rotate only along $z$ axis. Searching with google, I was only able to find the Verlet algorithm using quaternions.

Of course, quaternions are a good way to represent a rotational dynamics in 3D, but I would like to use something lighter since I'm concerned to solve dynamics in 2D.

Is there some resources that I can read in order to get through this problem?

With quaternions, I have to integrate $4$ equations for the rotational part, while I'm just interested in the rotation along $z$ axis.

**Update 05-18-2016**
The model I'm studying is the following:

\begin{cases}
\dot{x}(t) & = v_x(t) \\
m\dot{v}_x(t) & = -\lambda v_x(t) + F_x(x(t), y(t)) + R_x(t)\\
\dot{y}(t) & = v_y(t) \\
m\dot{v}_y(t) & = -\lambda v_y(t) + F_y(x(t), y(t)) + R_y(t)\\
\dot{\theta}(t) & = \omega(t) \\
I\dot{\omega}(t) & = -\eta\omega(t) + \tau(\theta(t), x(t), y(t)) + r(t)
\end{cases},

where

- $x(t)$, $y(t)$ is the position of the body
- $v_x(t)$, $v_y(t)$ are the velocity components of the body
- $\theta$ is the angular position of the body (rotation along $z$ axis passing from the center of gravity of the body)
- $\omega$ is the angular velocity
- $m$ is the mass of the body
- $I$ is the moment of inertia of the body (rotation along $z$ axis passing from the center of gravity of the body)
- $\lambda$, $\eta$ are friction coefficients
- $F$ is a force, $\tau$ is a torque
- $R_x(t)$, $R_y(t)$ and $r(t)$ are random force and torque, respectively.

It is not related to game development. I just need to integrate this to study the dynamics of this model.

Comment: Without more details it is difficult to understand what your problem is and what help you are looking for.  If the context is game development, have you tried Game Development SE?  The following website might also be useful : http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/math-and-physics/a-verlet-based-approach-for-2d-game-physics-r2714.

Comment: @sammygerbil Thanks a lot for the hint! Anyway, it is not for game development. I added more details in the main post.